# Django Account Activation Link can't use twice?

Tags: python, django, redux, django-users

I am using Django-Registraion-Redux for registering user. When user get register and click on account activation link it gets activated but if user again click on same the link it show the same message as previous. This is not technically correct.
So how to restrict user to click on the same link or how to show proper message to him

Comment: for me, it seems ok, if user clicks on a valid activation link and their account is already active, tell them everything is ok, no need to throw some error in their face.

Comment: yes but the error account is already active is not coming it show the same page

Comment: how do i display that-- account is already active

Comment: what you have done till now?? please provide your code.

Comment: i have just use django-registration-redux package

Comment: https://django-registration-redux.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 3):

You can override the activate view, check for the requested user is active or not. If user is not active, activate it or else if user is already active then redirect to the error page showing something like `account already activated..`

do something like this..

```
def activate(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.user.is_active:
         return render(request, alredy_active.html, {})
    else:
        request.user.is_active = True
        request.user.save()
        return render(request, success.html, {})
```

Comment: should i set url for it

Comment: activate url is already there, all you need is override that. also you need to set the error url pointing  that already active view

Answer (score 0):

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    # They already have an account; don't let them register again
    return render_to_response('template-name', {})
```

Here we are checking user is authenticated or not with the help of this statement `request.user.is_authenticated()`, if user is authenticated then render response to your customized template.